# Difference between queries with grouped

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new to **mongodb**, and I have 2 queries: 
frist:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        $and : [
        { "imdb.rating": { $lt: 7 }},
        {$and: [ {"genres": { "$ne": "Crime" } }, {"genres": { "$ne": "Horror" } }]},
        {$and: [ {"languages": { "$eq": "English" } }, {"languages": { "$eq": "Japanese" } }]},
        {$or: [ {"rated": { "$eq": "PG" } }, {"rated": { "$eq": "G" } }]}

        ]

                }
    }
]).itcount()
```

The result its: 23

And now with this:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
         "imdb.rating": { $lt: 7 },
         $and: [ {"genres": { "$ne": "Crime" } }, {"genres": { "$ne": "Horror" } }],
         $or: [ {"rated": { "$eq": "PG" } }, {"rated": { "$eq": "G" } }],
         $and: [ {"languages": { "$eq": "English" } }, {"languages": { "$eq": "Japanese" } }]

                }
    }
]).itcount()
```

The result its 25,

But now I can't understand what is the difference between two queries, can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functional difference.  `$match` implicitly is using `$and` when you provide more than one expression and a simple key:value expression is shorthand for `key: {$eq: value}` e.g.

```
$match: {a:3, b:"buzz"}
```

is shorthand for:

```
$match: {$and: [{a:{$eq:3}}, {b:{$eq:"buzz"}} ] }
```

Comment: and why the results it's no same?

Comment: Whoa; did I misread?   I thought the second version ALSO returned 23 and you just wanted guidance on shorthand.  OK.    Could you post 1 or 2 example docs from the movies collection?   Among other things, the $and for languages $eq English and Japanese can never be true.